# How to make quick-calc output a result rounded with just 1 digit precision—1/7 = 0.1, not 0.142857142857?

Tags: calc

The title basically already says it all. Just one addition. I need quick-calc to act like that for just 2 times a week. Usually I prefer the standard 12 digit precision.

I know how to achieve this format in org mode spreadsheets:
Simply attach `;%.1f` at the end of a formula below the spreadsheet, and the result will be reformated to 1 decimal. But I really don't want to convert my whole calculation into an org mode spreadsheet just to get this one part of it rounded to 1 decimal.

I've searched GNU manual & searched with web search engine—in vein.

I've tried `C-u 1 M-x quick-calc`, but the result had the usual 12 digit precision.
`C-u M-x quick-calc` and `C-u C-u M-x quick-calc` also don't do the trick.
Inspired by GNU manual I looked shortly into calc mode, not quick-calc, although that's really not with what I want to work. I did so just to get some clues for how to achieve 1 digit rounded output format in quick-calc. In calc-mode I pressed `p 1`, but that just caused a prompt telling me that the digit precision must be at least 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Quick-Calculator) says:

> The Quick Calculator refers to
>   the ‘*Calculator*’ buffer for all mode settings.  Thus, for example, to
>   set the precision that the Quick Calculator uses, simply run the full
>   Calculator momentarily and use the regular ‘p’ command.

Similarly, you can run the full Calculator once and set `d f 1`. From that point on,  calc and quick-calc results will be displayed with one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Switching to calc mode, entering ```d f 1```, and then switching away from calc mode and then using ```M-x quick-calc``` works.